# Phonegap pages running on device faster or slower than opening same pages through a server

Tags: android, ios, performance, cordova

I am developing a cross-platform Phonegap application. What I wanted to know is if whether creating the Phonegap project directly on the device would be faster than running the same Phonegap project through a server (running through a server meaning, the project would be located on a remote computer and the app on the device would just redirect to the Phonegap webpages on the remote computer)?

Comment: Network I/O usually takes time, so the answer to your question should be obvious. That suggests to me that I do not understand your question properly.

Comment: Lets see-  in both cases you'd be running the same code on the same VM.  One way you're adding in a round trip over the network, the other you aren't.  Which do you think would be faster?

Comment: KK got it, that's the answer I was expecting. I am using the over the server implementation right now, but thats because I want to change data in the sql database, and with phonegap running on the device I am unable to do that. This should be another question but w/e, do u guys know of a way to access the sql database and having the phonegap and php pages locally on the device at the same time?

Comment: You cannot have php files in a phonegap app. But you can always use javascript to make ajax request to a remote server and ask for data.

Comment: Something that's not being brought up yet - you must include a majority of your app in the app, iOS will deny your app if it relies too much on a server for serving up app content. Also if you do this - make sure you have catches for users who don't have a connection.